# My case switch is return me nothing

Tags: php

I have this case switch that is grab data from sql database but is not working with what i'm trying to do. I want to output the return of cases. See my code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "table");
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM sections WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'] . " ");
$id = $_GET['id'];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $sections = $row['section'];

    $sec = function($sections) {
        switch ($sections) {
            case "Solo":
                return "2:10"; // time limit
                break;
            case "Duo/Trio/Quartet":
                return "2:10"; // time limit
                break;
            case "Formation":
                return "4:20"; //time limit
                break;
            case "Groups":
                return "3:40"; //time limit
                break;
        }
    };

    $time_limit = $sec();
}

echo "Your moment has $time_limit seconds"; // example
```

Comment: You're passing in `$sections`, but using `$section`. Why are you using an anonymous function instead of just assigning the variable?

Comment: @aynber gotta love the (stealth) edit they made.

Comment: My bad, i have edited my qestion.

Comment: so tell us Alex; what does PHP's error reporting and `mysqli_error($link)` reveal?

Comment: Error: Missing argument 1 for {closure}()

Comment: Well then... I think you have your answer... `$time_limit = $sec($sections);`

Comment: You are **wide open to SQL injections** and should use **Prepared Statements** instead of concatenate your queries. Specially since you're not escaping your inputs _at all_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I woudn't use an anonymous function here. You can assign the time_limit to the variable directly.

```
<?PHP
$link       = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "table");
$q          = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM sections WHERE id = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['id'] . " "));
$time_limit = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $sections = $row['section'];
    switch ($sections) {
        case "Solo":
            $time_limit = "2:10"; //time limit
            break;
        case "Duo/Trio/Quartet":
            $time_limit = "2:10"; //time limit
            break;
        case "Formation":
            $time_limit = "4:20"; //time limit
            break;
        case "Groups":
            $time_limit = "3:40"; //time limit
            break;
    }
}
echo "Your moment has $time_limit seconds"; // example
?>
```

Also: It's a very bad idea to use user input unsanitised, since your code is vulnerable for SQL-Injection attacks. Therefore I've added [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Well.... honestly we don't know his charset, so its better to suggest prepared statements for full safety across all conditions. But definitely... no point in the anon func for what he needs.

Comment: Inded, prepared statement is always the best thing to use.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() is for strings, not integers (hence the name "string"). If you want to escape integers (without using prepared statements), a simple cast will do: `intval($_GET['id'])`. At least that won't break the query if a non numeric value is passed in, which the above example would.

Comment: Well, no. It's perfectly fine for numbers in the way the SQL statement is used here. The statement doesn't care about PHP's internal storage of the ID, so it's really not important whether the ID is a string or number. For me personally, it's not good to interpret "7a" as 7 since it's simply a wrong request which should result in 0 entries.

Comment: As @MagnusEriksson said though, casting `7a` to an int would be cleaner than an unsafe escape string. Especially since that 'string' will end up in a query without single-quotes around it.

Comment: I don&#39;t care about PHP&#39;s internal storage in this case. Just as @IncredibleHat says, a non numric value would _break_ the query: `id = abc` is not valid SQL